# Django `if` statement isn't working?

Tags: django

In my template, I added the following debugging statement:

```
<script>
  console.log("leaderboard? {{ client_settings.LEADERBOARD_ENABLED }}");
</script>
```

On the console, I see:

```
[14:09:20.026] "leaderboard? false"
```

Later in my code, I have the following code:

```
{% if client_settings.LEADERBOARD_ENABLED %}
<button data-theme='a' onClick="$('.leaderboard').slideDown();">Leaderboard</button>
{% endif %}
```

which I would think cause the Leaderboard button not to appear... but it does! Can anyone see why this is?

Comment: can you show the way the setting is initialized ? `LEADERBOARD_ENABLED = ??` most likely you have a string there. change it to `LEADERBOARD_ENABLED=False`

Comment: @karthikr It would appear from that console printout it is `"false"`. It is set in a Django admin panel with a Yes/No switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python value for boolean false is stringified "False" with a capital F. Since your console statement has "false" with lowercase f, the value of `client_settings.LEADERBOARD_ENABLED` is probably the string `"false"`, which would be interpreted as boolean True.

The Pythonic way to change this would be to use `True` and `False` when setting the `LEADERBOARD_ENABLED` variable, instead of the strings `"true"` and `"false"`. If that is not feasible, you could change the template test to:

```
{% if client_settings.LEADERBOARD_ENABLED == "true" %}
```

Comment: Great, what's the easiest way to fix this in the templating language?